# What did Mr. Monk major in?

Tags: monk

In the show "Monk", we hear in few episodes that Monk went to university, and in at least one, that he studied in Berkley ("Mr. Monk and the other detective"). Are there some other hints, whether in the show or official extra material, indicating what he majored in?

Comment: Did he graduate? to call as to be majored in, someone has to graduate or atleast complete the course, innit?

Comment: @Vishwa In the US, having a major does not require one to graduate. Generally at an American university you have to be admitted to a specific department of the university, and many times to a specific program. That is your major. Some programs allow you to attend many classes before you have “declared” your major. And many classes require you to have a declared major that the class is part of to register for the class.

Answer (score 2):

Monk studied *Criminology, Police Science* or a similar course.

> Monk looked to the front of the room. “Is that Professor Jeremiah Cowan?”
> “Yeah, you know him?” Stottlemeyer said.
> “I took his **Introduction to Criminal Law class** when I was at Berkeley.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Mr. Monk and the Dirty Cop](https://monk.fandom.com/wiki/Mr._Monk_and_the_Dirty_Cop)</sup></sub>

Currently Berkeley offers its Intro to Criminal Law programme as part of their [Justice Studies](https://berkeleycollege.edu/catalogs/undergraduate-2021-2022/academics-programs/course-descriptions/school-of-professional-studies-courses/justice-studies-courses/index.html) curriculum, but in the 1970s they had something called the [*School of Criminology*](https://www.foundsf.org/index.php?title=UC_Berkeley:_The_Closure_of_the_School_of_Criminology,_1976), aimed at current and would-be police officers seeking to gain qualifications in crime detection and management.